How are God, angels, men and devils related, according to the Scriptures?
I see a lot of pseudo-Scriptural mysticism on the subject of the identities of angels and devils, men and God. I say mysticism not to dismiss attempted explanations categorically, but because the Scriptures do not seem to say explicitly that men and angels, God and man, and even man and devils are not (or were not once) of the same kin. Yet it is common to see whole theologies that rely on some kind of eternal genetic or pseudo-genetic distinction between God and man, and angels and man, which naturally gives rise to complex soteriologies and speculations such as that otherworldly creatures or fallen angels have interbred with humans, giving rise to giants and so on, despite no such genetic distinction being apparently drawn in the Biblical text; only the use of different, possibly synonymous terms in different places. Does any such distinction exist, or are the terms not synonymous in terms of origin, heritage, kind or type?
There are some notable cultural distinctions of caricature. We see descriptions of angels as having wings, but it is not clear whether these are literal or figurative. I am not sure where horns for devils come from, apart from John's descriptions of the beasts of worldly and Satanic power.
There are depictions such as Isaiah's vision of the Lord on His throne surrounded by seraphs, and it is not always immediately clear to the reader whether such depictions are to be taken as metaphorical or actual beings as to their attributes (having six wings, etc.).
What is the Scriptural evidence delineating God(s), angels, men and devils as to their original identity and genetics or one-time kinship, if any? Or do the Scriptures demonstrate any kind of genetic relation between them, so to speak? Are "classes" of beings to be understood as eternal barriers, or acquirable statuses of the creature?
This is related to the questions
Origin of the idea that "demons" and "fallen angels" are the same thing?, and How are angels and humans different?, but is intended to be more general and comprehensive in scope across these classes of beings.
What denominations have teachings on this subject specifying the relationships among these types of beings, and what Scriptural citations do they use to corroborate their views?
Were these four types of beings originally all one type of being? What is the end of man in relation to these classes?

This question needs to be scoped to a distinct part of modern, self-identifying 'Christianity'. The various views (and they will be conflicting views) will be multitudinous as the question is also extremely broad taking in Deity, angelic powers, demonic spirits and humanity - their origins, relationships and interactions. The question admits that it seeks to be 'general and comprehensive in scope'. I think it is unrealistic to expect this site to encompass all that is required when multiple viewpoints are invited to participate in such a very, very broad exercise.

@NigelJ, on the other hand, it does say "according to the Scriptures".

@NigelJ Sigh... This would apply to every Biblical Basis question if it is not already further qualified with an overview request or narrowed to a specific domination... Either that entire question category (and practically every other category) needs to be erased from the site unless further specified to a denomination or expressed as a denominational overview, or it should be generally understood that questions that are not denomination-specific are asking for an overview. Why not adopt this latter standard since naturally every question is either specified to a denomination or overview?

The relationship between God and everything else is Creator-Creation. Everything in Creation you might organize into some taxonomy, but God is explicitly outside of it and He stands alone. In fact, that's literally what Holy means. The amount of "kinship" between the rest is not really a biblical matter, as in, it's not really talked about. You have to dive deep into other writings to learn what has been supposed.

'What is the scriptural evidence delineating Gods . . . .  ?' needs to be scoped to people who believe in 'Gods'.

@user1934286 Did God create devils? Doesn't the Bible talk about God's kin?

@NigelJ The term is intended to be inclusive enough for those who believe in modalism as well as those who believe that God the Father is the Son of Jesus Christ, and in the Godhead more generally.

I am not aware that anyone believes that 'God the Father is the Son of Jesus Christ'.

@NigelJ Sorry for the confusion--Wrote this in a state of mental tongue-twisting. Jesus Christ is the Son of God the Father.

The question asks for an answer "according to the Scriptures", and specifically, "What denominations have teachings on this subject specifying the relationships among these types of beings, and what Scriptural citations do they use to corroborate their views? Were these four types of beings originally all one type of being? What is the end of man in relation to these classes?"
Some answers quote from texts that they regard as "Scripture" but which the denomination teaching I use in my answer does not. They regard "Scripture" as being the 39 books of the Hebrew Scriptures plus the 27 books of the Christian Greek Scriptures, that is, the Bible. The denominational view-point I give is that of Reformed Protestantism, and I use texts from the Bible to support this.
God, his being, and how all created beings relate to him
This is answered in the Westminster Confession of Faith II headed, Of God, particularly II.2:

"God hath all life, glory, goodness, blessedness, in and of himself;
and is alone into and unto himself all-sufficient, not standing in
need of any creatures which he hath made, not deriving any glory from
them, but only manifesting his own glory, in, by, unto, and upon them:
He is the alone fountain of all being, of whom, through whom, and to
whom, are all things; and hath most sovereign dominion over them, to
do by them, for them, or upon them, whatsoever himself pleaseth.
In his sight all things are open and manifest; his knowledge is
infinite, infallible, and independent.
He is most holy in all his counsels, in all his works, and in all his
commands.
To him is due from angels and men, and every other creature,
whatsoever worship, service, or obedience, he is pleased to require of
them." Westminster Confession of Faith II.2

Biblical texts are used to support all of this but sticking to just the points asked about in this question, a couple of sample texts are: Genesis 1:1, Acts 17:25,
Angels
The Bible shows that angels are God's messengers who assist humans who seek God and who serve him faithfully. Much of the book of Revelation speaks of angels doing all that. Galatians 3:19 gives one example of angelic service to Moses. But humans must never adore angels - Colossians 2:18. God has kept from angels certain things that he first revealed to faithful humans - 1 Peter 1:12
Devils
As a study guide on the WCF states regarding evil (which includes all spiritual evil - demons etc) "Even evil has come into existence because it was God's good pleasure to permit it, in order that by means of it his good purpose might be accomplished - Isaiah 45:7."
Jude verse 6 informs us that the angels which forsook their first estate /habitation (heaven), leaving it to join with the arch-rebel, are reserved in everlasting chains under darkness until the judgment of the great day.
The Bible states that all devils / demons, and their leader, are destined for the eternally burning lake of sulphuric fire. where their torment knows no end - Revelation 20:10 & 14:11.
Man - his end in relation to those classes
Job 11:6-11 shows man being measured against God, and it is truly humbling:

"God exacteth of thee less than thine iniquity deserveth. Canst thou
by searching find out God? Canst thou find out the Almighty unto
perfection? It is as high as heaven; what canst thou do? deeper than
hell; what canst thou know... For he knoweth vain men: he seeth
wickedness also; will he not then consider it?" Job 11:6-11 A.V.

But for proud humanity that does not relate to God as their sovereign and only God, the Bible states that God's wrath is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men who hold the truth in unrighteousness - see Romans 1:17-20.
Humans are warned in the Bible not to adore, worship angels - Colossians 2:18. God has favoured faithful humans to first have knowledge of certain things that were kept from angels - 1 Peter 1:12.
Humans can only relate to God as "sons of God" if God grants them the new, spiritual birth, from above. See John 1:1-13 and 3:1-16. That releases them from the condemnation that remains upon all humans not so "born again". Man's ultimate end depends on this: Those born again have God as their heavenly Father (spiritually) while Jesus showed that those who hate him have made Satan the devil their ‘father’ (spiritually – John 8:42 – nothing to do with physical genetics.
Summary: All life is given by God, who also sustains life. God is unique. Angels (from which some became devils) were created by God (hence, creatures). Men were created by God (hence, creatures). God is not a creature. The Bible says nothing about 'genetic' connections between those 4 categories the question asks about. There are spiritual connections, briefly mentioned in this answer. The Bible is clear that the 3 created categories could never be, originally, the one unique God of all creation.
The purpose of man, in the will of God, is to bring glory to God as their Creator. Those who will not do that shall have an eternity to reflect on what total alienation from the source of Life, Light and Truth means - in company of the devils who deceive humanity, who seek to lead humanity away from God. John 3:36 & 5:23-24. As Jesus Christ came into the world as its Creator, Light and Life and Truth (John chapter 1), those who receive him, who believe in his name, have everlasting life in glory - John 6:40 & 44-47.

God
In various languages, terms for "God" and "Lord" have meanings and connotations including "Master", "Elder", "Senior", "the Almighty", "Creator", "Keeper of Loaves", "Sustainer", "Good", "Great Father", "The Most High", "Chief", to name just a few of His titles. It stands to reason that the Most High Being, the Creator, the Chief of all, is God.
Angels
Angel means "messenger". God has angels (messengers or representatives of righteousness) and the devil has angels (messengers or representatives of wickedness). There is no language anywhere in Scripture distinguishing angels from humans genetically, only by calling or appointment, by righteousness or stage of existence.
Men
"Man" should hopefully be self-explanatory in present company. God formed man out of the dust of the Earth, creating both man and woman in the image and likeness of Deity, and breathed into man his spirit. (Genesis 2:7)
Mankind is referred to frequently and affirmed unanimously throughout Scripture to be offspring of God.

For in him we live, and move, and have our being; as certain also of your own poets have said, For we are also his offspring.
Forasmuch then as we are the offspring of God, we ought not to think that the Godhead is like unto gold, or silver, or stone, graven by art and man’s device. (Acts 17:28-29)

This idea is so repugnant to Satan that he tempts religious leaders of the world to regard it as blasphemy, and worthy of death, to say that mankind are children of God.

The Jews answered him, saying, For a good work we stone thee not; but for blasphemy; and because that thou, being a man, makest thyself God.
Jesus answered them, Is it not written in your law, I said, Ye are gods?
If he called them gods, unto whom the word of God came, and the scripture cannot be broken;
Say ye of him, whom the Father hath sanctified, and sent into the world, Thou blasphemest; because I said, I am the Son of God? (John 10:33-36, see Psalm 82:6)

Our capacity through the Son of God is to become as the Father is:

The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the children of God
And if children, then heirs; heirs of God, and joint-heirs with Christ; if so be that we suffer with him, that we may be also glorified together. (Romans 8:16-17)

Devils
Devils are slanderers. A third part of the host of heaven followed Lucifer in his rebellion against God, and became devils. Sometimes they are referred to as fallen angels, and this is correct.

How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations! (Isaiah 14:12)


The Son of man goeth as it is written of him: but woe unto that man by whom the Son of man is betrayed! it had been good for that man if he had not been born. (Matthew 26:24)

Devils will never have physical bodies. This is contrasted with unclean spirits, which had a body but were wicked during their mortal lives and are now disembodied.
One kind, one family, with opposition
The Scriptures attest that the spirit of man is the offspring of God.
God, angels, men and devils were from the beginning all the same kind of being, are all men (or women) and were intended to be of one eternal family, but some have rebelled. Angels are those who still reside in the presence of God and are His messengers. Men can become angels to God if they are worthy, and those who have ministered in the capacity of angels and have not rebelled against God will be born as mortal men if they have not yet. Devils are those angels or spirits who rebelled against God while in His presence. As such they cannot progress and are damned, and will never receive a body. The end of man is to become as God, or to be an angel to God forever, or to become as the devil, or any degree in between.

Jesus told us that they in the resurrection will be 'as' the angels. Not they will be angels (an angel to God for ever [sic]). Humanity, resurrected, are to be the sons of God. ... to bring many sons to glory. All we are going to get in answer to this question is a variety of opinions, which will be contested.

@NigelJ He said this to those who did not believe in the resurrection. While admitting that the mysteries of the kingdom are kept hidden from those who do not wish to hear them. For their purposes, their is no marriage in a resurrection that, according to themselves, does not exist in the first place.
The notion that being angels forever is all there is contradicts what the Savior and the Apostles regarding the Divine origin and potential of man.
The Lord knows the answer. Do His people?

"God, angels, men and devils were from the beginning all the same kind of being" — What evidence is there for this claim?

@RayButterworth This is abundantly clear from the Scriptures. Lucifer fell from heaven and became the devil; he was once an angel (Revelation 12:7-9). Men can become angels (as Gabriel, Michael or Rafael, see Luke 1:26–38) or as devils through unrepented sin. Mankind are children of God who can become as the Son of God (Romans 8:16-17), Who is as the Father (John 14).

"Men can become angels (as Gabriel, Michael or Rafael, see Luke 1:26–38)" — That says nothing about men becoming angels.

The relationship between the 3 basic things that exist.
God, Angels, and Humans.
God, currently understood as the Trinity. Was the one who is uncreated, and created everything else. Almighty and Loving.
Angels, a created being of a spirit nature, created before the material world, they are outside our comprehension governed by different "fundamental laws", they seek to help mankind.
Humans, a created being of a physical/spiritual nature, we are within our comprehension of "fundamental laws", we were intended to rule over all of creation. (that would have included angels)
Devils/demons, a created being of spirit nature, an angel that rejected God, they seek to ruin humanity out of spite, envy, resentment, hate, etc. and are generally "parasitic"

I will only answer part of the question, because to go into such detail is not feasible. Each of those interactions is book worthy.
But I will point out flat out that God is not a "being" as we understand it. All of creation has beings, and a being is created. God is something else, something "uncreated" and we do not understand that very well.
Angels and Humans are both beings, that were created. Yes. Though not the same being. I will focus primarily on what we understand of angels, without going into exhaustive detail...  Short answer below (chuckles to himself and starts writing)


Angels are pure spirits. They are created, but not the same way we human beings are. Some had fallen from heaven along with Satan, about whom Jesus Himself said: “I beheld Satan fall from heaven like lightning” (Luke 10:18). (Quote from Very Rev. Vladimir Berzonsky, (Angels and Human beings]1)


‘An angel, then, is an intelligent essence, in perpetual motion, with free will, incorporeal, ministering to God, having obtained by grace an immortal nature: and the Creator alone knows the form and limitation of its essence’ (Saint John the Damascan, Exact Exposition of the Orthodox Faith, Book 2, Chapter 3, "on Angels")

The angelic nature has intelligence and reason, but not the life-giving spirit, because it didn’t receive an earthly body, and therefore the spirit can’t be a  cohesive force for it (the body). (based on Gregory Palamas "150 natural, theological, ethical, and practical chapters" Philokalia.)

I believe that the angels are ... noetic beings created by God, ... they possess a different nature than ours, their spiritual and incorporeal nature is nonetheless real and is subject to other laws and other dimensions foreign to human nature. They are conscious persons. In the beginning they were created perfectly good, perfectly free, having the faculty of will and choice. Some angels made a good choice by remaining faithful to their Creator, whereas others used their liberty in an evil manner and estranged themselves from their Creator and rose up against Him and, becoming darkened and wicked, fell from God and turned into demons.
The demons are envious of man because of the glory of the eternal destiny for which he was created, and they seek his ruin and utter destruction. They have no real power over those who have received Baptism, yet they tempt us so that we ourselves might make ill use of our freedom.
But the angels, because of their loyalty and their communion with God, know no envy and are not jealous of man's destiny. Rather, they have been endowed with a nature superior to man's so that they might help man realize his purpose through the aid of Divine Grace; they rejoice when a man succeeds in realizing the aim of his existence. ... All beings created by God's wisdom, will, and love are fashioned on a hierarchical principle and not on an egalitarian principle. Even as men on earth differ according to what gift each has received, so also do the angels have distinctions among themselves in accordance with their rank and their ministry.
Father Alexander

Continuing in with the wisdom of Palamas, we do not know when or how, but those angels that remained true by choice were crystallized by grace in will. They had their autonomy sanctified. So they can do whatever they choose, but by grace they will always do what is right.

They aren’t however, entirely bodiless, a feature which is true only of God. In relation to God, they’re embodied, but compared to us they’re bodiless (Saint John the Damascan, op. cit.)

Angels are attributed with a kind of ‘ethereal and arial’ body.

‘when they are in heaven, they are not on earth and when they are sent by God down to the earth they do not remain in heaven’ (Saint John the Damascan, op. cit.)

That is to say they are circumscribed or limited, they are not everywhere at once. Though they are "really fast" These immaterial powers (of speed) "have no bounds" (Ibid.)
Another important aspect is that angels are not all knowing. and any "prophecies" of the future are via God. This is important to know, it is a way a demon can trick you into thinking they speak of the future. A demon is very smart, and will be able to go and see some distant event, and it will seem as prophecy.

This spiritual writing is based on the scriptures:
We know they exist.
Mankind knew about the existence of angels from their first days in Paradise. From Genesis we know that a Cherubim was placed with a flaming sword at the gates of Paradise after Adam and Eve were expelled. Later, Abraham encouraged his servant Nahor telling him that the Lord would send His angel with him to protect him. (Gen 34:7). Jacob saw angels during his sleep and while awake. (Gen 32:1-2).
They have no bodily needs or desires, no cares about food, drink, etc. They do not procreate. They neither marry nor are given in marriage (Matt. 22:30)
There are a great number of Angels.

A fiery stream issued
And came forth from before Him.
A thousand thousands ministered to Him;
Ten thousand times ten thousand stood before Him.
The court was seated,
And the books were opened. (Daniel 7:10)

We know they have different "degrees" or ranks.

Yet Michael the archangel... (Jude 9a)


For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God. And the dead in Christ will rise first. (1 Thes 4:16)

We know there are different types of angels.

The Seraphim (Means flaming): are aflame with love for God and kindle others to such love. They are closest to God as the prophet Isaiah saw, saying: "And the seraphim stood around Him, each having six wings" (Isaiah 6:2). They are fire-like, "For our God is a consuming fire." (Heb 12:29); "His throne was a flame of fire" (Dan 7:9), "Who maketh his angels spirits; his ministers a flaming fire" (Ps 103:4).

The Cherubim, We see them guarding the garden in Gen. 3:24, They are many-eyed and many-faced and radiant with knowledge of the mysteries of God. Through the cherubim wisdom is sent down to others. With their multiple faces and wings, embody the multifaceted nature of God’s wisdom and sovereignty. They serve as a reminder of the divine order and the complexity of God’s creation.



“Their whole body, their backs, their hands, and their wings were full of eyes all around, even the wheels that the four of them had.” (Ezekiel 10:12)


The God-Bearing thrones: (Galgalim/Ophaninn/Wheels)


(as St. Dionysius the Areopagite calls them) before Him Who sits on the high and exulted throne, being named "thrones" since on them, as on intellectual thrones (as writes St. Maximus the Confessor) God intellectually resides. They are not called "God-bearing" according to essence but according to grace and according to their office, as the flesh of Jesus Christ (as St. Basil the Great writes) is called "God-bearing" according to essence since it was indivisibly united with God the Word Himself. The thrones are then called "God-bearing" not according to essence but according to grace, given for their service, which is mystically and incomprehensibley to bear God in themselves. Residing on them in an incomprehensible manner, God makes His righteous judgement, according to the word of David: "Thou hast sat upon a throne, O Thou that judgest righteousness" (Ps 9:4). Therefore through them the justice of God is pre-eminently manifested; they serve His justice, glorifying it and pouring out the power of justice onto the thrones of earthly judges, helping kings and masters to bring forth right judgement.  (https://orthodoxwiki.org/Thrones)

They are also described in the Book of Ezekiel, and have popularly been seen in artwork online now. (What people think angels look like vs what ezekiel described)
There are of course even more types, including simple angels, guardian angels, archangels, and so on. There are many types.
They are fast.

Then it happened, when I, Daniel, had seen the vision and was seeking the meaning, that suddenly there stood before me one having the appearance of a man. (Daniel 8:15)


yes, while I was speaking in prayer, the man Gabriel, whom I had seen in the vision at the beginning, being caused to fly swiftly, reached me about the time of the evening offering. (Daniel 9:21)


I saw by night, and behold, a man riding on a red horse, and it stood among the myrtle trees in the hollow; and behind him were horses: red, sorrel, and white. (Zech. 1:8)

They are not all knowing and do not understand everything. They didn't know God's plan for the incarnation or salvation. They do not know the depths of the essence of God either.

...and to make all see what is the fellowship of the mystery, which from the beginning of the ages has been hidden in God who created all things through Jesus Christ; to the intent that now the manifold wisdom of God might be made known by the church to the principalities and powers in the heavenly places (Ephesians 3:9-10)


To them it was revealed that, not to themselves, but to us they were ministering the things which now have been reported to you through those who have preached the gospel to you by the Holy Spirit sent from heaven—things which angels desire to look into. (1 Peter 1:12)


For what man knows the things of a man except the spirit of the man which is in him? Even so no one knows the things of God except the Spirit of God. (1 Corinthians 2:11)

They do NOT know the future.

But of that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father. (Mark 13:32)

They are incorporeal, a sort of spirit or immaterial fire. Fire does not have a body, but it is very real. Thus also are the bodies of angels.

His angels are spirits , and His ministers a flame of fire (Ps 103:6).

They don't know human thoughts.

...then hear in heaven Your dwelling place, and forgive, and act, and give to everyone according to all his ways, whose heart You know (for You alone know the hearts of all the sons of men), (3rd Kings 8:39)


Angels have tasks.

To glorify God
To assist Humans.

The second of the two is described by Saint Basil the Great as circumstantial, since it was assigned to the angels after our creation. It is the belief of the Church, based on Biblical and Patristic testimony.
This is found in the following scriptures.

Above it stood seraphim; each one had six wings: with two he covered his face, with two he covered his feet, and with two he flew. And one cried to another and said:
“Holy, holy, holy is the Lord of hosts;
The whole earth is full of His glory!” (Isaiah 6:2-3)

In Genesis 24:7, Exodus 23:20, and in Tobit 5: An angel goes before people as a guiding manner.

Then I said, “My lord, what are these?” So the angel who talked with me said to me, “I will show you what they are.” (Zech 1:9)

We also know that we have a "guardian angel", that is also based on scripture.

“Take heed that you do not despise one of these little ones, for I say to you that in heaven their angels always see the face of My Father who is in heaven.

We also see an angel in Acts 20:5-18 while Peter is in prison, the angel helps Peter escape prison. (Herod's prison)

"The [guardian] angel will not retreat from us, unless we drive him away by our evil deeds. As the smoke drives bees away, and stench the doves, even so our stinking sin drives away from us the angel who protects our life." - Saint Basil the Great



Right so that's angels. What about demons? ... this question is too broad, as another section just as long as this would be able to be written to describe how demons are and how they interact with humanity. And then another section, shorter...
And then much can be written about Humanity as well.

Short Answer
Were these four types of beings originally all one type of being? You are talking about 2 types of beings and God. Angels can be divided into those that follow God and Demons/devils who turned away from God. Man is a different kind of being from Angels. God is weird and strange, and different, we don't properly understand.
What is the end of man in relation to these classes? Man was supposed to be a ruler of all creation, but we failed. So God is rescuing us. Angels help. Demons do everything they can to make us fail to grasp God's "hand" as we drown.

I think your answer needs to add reference to the Ophaninn who in addition to the Cherubim and Seraphim guard the fiery throne of God. You can get that from the book of Enoch.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany To my understanding the book of Enoch does not mention the Ophaninn, it does however mention the Grigori (and the GIants/Nephilim). The book of Ezekiel however does mention the Galgalim/Ophaninn/Wheels and the Eastern Orthodox church describes them as "Thrones" which I did mention. However, I will put that title in my answer so it is more clear. But I will not mention the Grigori.

The angels (symbolized as stars) existed before the creation:

Job 38:4,7:
Where wast thou when I laid the foundations of the earth?
…
When the morning stars sang together, and all the sons of God shouted for joy?

Lucifer/Satan, rebelled against God:

Isaiah 14:
12 How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!
13 For thou hast said in thine heart, I will ascend into heaven, I will exalt my throne above the stars of God: I will sit also upon the mount of the congregation, in the sides of the north:
14 I will ascend above the heights of the clouds; I will be like the most High.
15 Yet thou shalt be brought down to hell, to the sides of the pit.


Ezekiel 28:12–16:
12 … Thus saith the Lord GOD; Thou sealest up the sum, full of wisdom, and perfect in beauty.
13 Thou hast been in Eden the garden of God; every precious stone was thy covering, the sardius, topaz, and the diamond, the beryl, the onyx, and the jasper, the sapphire, the emerald, and the carbuncle, and gold: the workmanship of thy tabrets and of thy pipes was prepared in thee in the day that thou wast created.
14 Thou art the anointed cherub that covereth; and I have set thee so: thou wast upon the holy mountain of God; thou hast walked up and down in the midst of the stones of fire.
15 Thou wast perfect in thy ways from the day that thou wast created, till iniquity was found in thee.
16 By the multitude of thy merchandise they have filled the midst of thee with violence, and thou hast sinned: therefore I will cast thee as profane out of the mountain of God: and I will destroy thee, O covering cherub, from the midst of the stones of fire.

He and his angels (now called demons) were banished from God's Heaven:

Revelation 12:
7 Then there was war in heaven. Michael and his angels fought against the dragon and his angels.
8 And the dragon lost the battle, and he and his angels were forced out of heaven.
9 This great dragon — the ancient serpent called the devil, or Satan, the one deceiving the whole world — was thrown down to the earth with all his angels.


Luke 10:18:
And [Jesus] said unto them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven.


Jude 1:6:
And the angels which kept not their first estate, but left their own habitation, he hath reserved in everlasting chains under darkness unto the judgment of the great day.

Eventually Satan and his followers will be cast into fire (and very likely destroyed):

Matthew 25:41:
Then shall he say also unto them on the left hand, Depart from me, ye cursed, into everlasting fire, prepared for the devil and his angels:


Revelation 20:10:
And the devil that deceived them was cast into the lake of fire and brimstone, …

Humans were created in the image of God, but currently they do not have the power of angels (neither did the incarnated Jesus):

Psalm 8:5:
For thou hast made him a little lower than the angels, and hast crowned him with glory and honour.


Hebrews 2:
7 Thou madest him a little lower than the angels; thou crownedst him with glory and honour, and didst set him over the works of thy hands:
8 Thou hast put all things in subjection under his feet. For in that he put all in subjection under him, he left nothing that is not put under him. But now we see not yet all things put under him.
9 But we see Jesus, who was made a little lower than the angels for the suffering of death, crowned with glory and honour; that he by the grace of God should taste death for every man.


Clearly there are very distinct categories of beings:

The Godhead is immortal and has always existed.
Various kinds of spirit beings were created.
Some of the spirit beings rebelled against God and were banished from God's Heaven.
Humans were created as physical beings, lesser than angels.
Humans will eventually become spirit beings, higher than the angels, reborn as siblings of Jesus.


The angels didn't exist before creation, just before the "foundation of the earth".

@curiousdannii, would "before the creation of Earth", or perhaps "before the seven days of creation", be acceptable?

Well that's a matter of opinion. Job doesn't discuss the days of creation, and Genesis 1 doesn't (explicitly) mention the angels.
